# Char equals char undesired output

Tags: c++, if-statement, char, equals

I am trying to create a simple c++ program which prints out if char is Y or y, N or n or neither.

After debugging I have found out that the if(chr == 'Y' || 'y') statement is true even though char variable is 'N'. Can anybody tell me why this if statement is true and not false?

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
char chr = 'N';

if (chr == 'Y' || 'y')
{
    cout << "chr is y" << endl;

}
else if (chr == 'N' || 'n')
{
    cout << "chr is n" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "chr is something else" << endl;
}
}
```

Comment: That doesn't do what you think it does. Use `chr == 'Y' || chr == 'y'` instead (and similar for `'n'` and `'N'`).

Comment: The condition `chr == 'Y' || 'y'` means "chr is equal to 'Y'; Or 'y'." Note the lack of comparison in the second part of the sentence. Your sentence should be like "chr is equal to 'Y'; Or chr is equal to 'y'."

Comment: See also `std::toupper` and `std::tolower` so you only have to make one comparison.

Answer (score 3):

This is not doing what you thing:

```
if (chr == 'Y' || 'y')
```

This is basically:

```
if (chr == 'Y' || true)
```

So in the end:

```
if (true)
```

You have to say what you compare:

```
if (chr == 'Y' || chr == 'y')
```

The operator `==` only takes one character, not a set of possible characters.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this

```
if (chr == 'Y' || 'y')
```

You need

```
if ((chr == 'Y') || (chr == 'Y'))
```

Likewise for the `'N'` and `'n'`.

It is also possible do it with one comparison:

```
if (toupper((unsigned char)chr) == 'Y')
```

This way, maintainability is slighly improved as only one value has to be changed should the letter change (for a different localization, per example).

Comment: One could also use `if (toupper(chr) == 'Y')` and not have to deal with addition checks. :-)

Comment: Great suggestion, I added it to the post.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews It [should](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper) be `toupper((unsigned char)chr)`. :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: the compiler will take care of the promotion, so the cast is not necessary.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Lack of the cast -> UB if passed character has a negative code (and isn't equal to `EOF`), as the link explains.